# SSRS expression needed to trim a string after specific instance of space/character

Tags: sql, string, reporting-services

I am trying to trim a long string which contains the time and date at the end in an expression in SSRS. For example, I have a string like below:

> cn=bob smith, ou=gastro, ou=bht, dc=hospital, dc=int jane doe 29 December 2015 15:12:44

and I am looking to extract the '**29 December 2015 15:12:44**' part. Unfortunately, all the other text parts of the string are variable, and as the month is written as the whole month name (rather than Jan/Feb etc) then that is also variable in length. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string comes from an SQL query, you can use a Regular Expression on the string in the query to get just the date.

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    'int jane doe 29 December 2015 15:12:44',
    '(\d)+\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|Novemeber|December)(.)+'
  ) date_text
FROM DUAL
```

This query is for an Oracle 11g database, and gives the result:

```
DATE_TEXT
29 December 2015 15:12:44
```

The regex looks for the first instance of a number followed by a month name, and gives it as a substring along with all characters afterwards to get the year and time. This assumes no other dates will be present, and the day and month will always be in this format (Not 29th Dec or December 29 etc.).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KVCh-_jI9bAJOaee)